# Launch kodi from startup and play track

Tags: boot, kodi, script

Sorry if its been answered a lot.  I am new to scripting and would like to know where I start to do this.  I want to script it myself but would like to know what I need to do to start kodi in fullscreen and play a song upon startup.  So when I unplug it and power it back on it resumes the content.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: first step would be to check the kodi documentation regarding how to start it from the command line. Then how to make it load a specific file. Then experiment invoking the command to open kodi and play a specific file. Next wrap that up in a script/cron job and test. Remember the best way to eat an elephant is one bite at a time. This google search should give you most of what you need https://www.google.com/search?q=man+kodi&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS497US497&oq=man+kodi&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1427j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=start+kodi+from+command+line

Answer (score 0):

Try this it goes into pretty good detail on what you are needing.
http://kodi.wiki/view/HOW-TO:Autostart_Kodi_for_Linux

Comment: We're trying a [new policy in order to clean up informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538).  If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Comment: Article's header says it is *OUTDATED*.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit is quite easy, you can simply install kodi via apt-get,

```
sudo apt-get install kodi -y
```

There is also a file `/etc/default/kodi`
Change the line `ENABLED=0` to `ENABLED=1` as far as starting playback of a song you will need to learn how to use The kodi api with Python to playback songs on startup.

Comment: File not present for version 17.* (aka Krypton).